# Grails error handling in controllers

Tags: grails

I would like to render custom JSON error messages. I created the following controller:

```
class ErrorController {

    static responseFormats = ['json']

    def notAuthorized() {
        render([error: "You are not authorized to access ${request.getRequestURL()} on this server.",
                path: request.getRequestURI()] as JSON)
    }
}
```

Inside the `UrlMappings` class I have the following:

```
"401"(controller: 'error', action: 'notAuthorized')
```

Everything works alright, except for the fact that I `GET http://localhost/path` the following error message:

```
{"error":"You are not authorized to access http://localhost:8080/error on this server.",
 "path":"/error"}
```

So the URI/URL in the `request` object does not point to the URI/URL given by the request. Is there a way to obtain the correct URI/URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is `request.forwardURI`. That should give you the request that triggered the error.